# Unable to schedule VB Script to run whether user is logged on or not

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a small VB Script that does the following

1. Access an Excel file in a network path
2. Run a macro in it
3. Save the Excel as a CSV in the same path

Below is the code of the same

```
Set objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objexcel.Interactive = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
objexcel.Visible = FALSE

objexcel.Application.Run "'\\network_path\XL_Filename.xlsm'!MacroName"

objexcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objexcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("\\network_path\CSV_Filename.csv"), 6
objexcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objexcel.Quit
```

When its run from my machine manually, the code executes perfectly. The trouble is when I try to schedule this VBS in Windows Task Scheduler.

In the Scheduler, if I select "Run only when user is logged on", it runs fine. However, if instead I select "Run whether user is logged on or not", the task gets stuck at Running.

The Action in Task is `"%windir%\syswow64\cscript.exe" //nologo //B "C:\Users\MyID\Documents\Script.VBS"`

I have tried everything I know and read online

- Making sure to use CSCRIPT and no interactive elements
- Checking folder accesses and ID accesses (incl. DCOMCNFG)
- Creating folders C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop and  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
- Running with admin rights
- Disabling UAC

Nothing seems to work. Could someone please help me figure out what am I not doing correctly?!

Comment: Add logging to your script, to see where it actually hangs (something like `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").LogEvent 4, "some marker"` after each statement). That will probably show that the issue is caused by the macro you're invoking, so you'd need to do the same thing there. Report back with your findings if you need further help.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the tip. I tried adding a log entry before and after every line of the above code to find where the issue is. It looks like, in "Run whether user is logged on or not" mode, the code gets stuck at the very first line of creating Excel object! It's not executing even that one line successfully.

Comment: Did you try running the script with the 64-bit interpreter (`%windir%\system32\cscript.exe`)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, I did. Same result. Gets stuck at the first line.

Comment: Weird. Any auto-loading workbooks/macros perhaps? Do you get the same behavior if you start the task under a different (new) user?